# Growth mixture models, "structural parameters", and using a parameter with variance fixed at zero as mediator in regression model?

Tags: random-effects-model, growth-mixture-model

I am examining a paper that uses growth mixture modeling. They have estimated intercept, linear slope, and quadratic growth parameters. They have also estimated random effects for the intercept and linear slope. However, they have set the variance of the quadratic slope to zero (which I understand to be using fixed effects for that parameter).

They have stated that because they fixed the variance of the quadratic slope to zero, this parameter could not be used in the 'structural part of the model'.

I am just wanting to learn a bit about why this may be. I presume that 'structural parameters' are just normal parameters of the model? Is there a better definition for this? What are non-structural parameters?

Also, is it correct that this parameter cannot be used in regression analyses because its variance is fixed at zero? I would assume that you could used fixed effects parameters in regression?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Cheers! -George

Comment: IMO it is always a good idea to cite the paper you are discussing. (I see no conflict here - it is not as if you are being critical anyway.)

Comment: Thanks Andy. Actually the paper has not been published yet- I am reviewing it. Their analyses are all fine and done properly. It is just the use of the term structural parameter that I am not familiar with. Also, it is entirely reasonable that they did not use the quadratic growth parameter in analyses, it is just their rationale being because they set it's variance to zero. So I just want to have a better understanding of this before making a comment.